# How to modify a td element to be a hyperlink in JSP using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

In my JSP page I am fetching values from a sql statement in a ArrayList, which is getting created as table content. a set of values in this list would be a `url`. How can I convert this particular td element (the one with url) to be a hyperlink action item?

Here is the jsp code

```
<table border="1" id="tableView">
    <thead>
        <th></th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Active</th><th>Release Date</th><th>Url</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <%
    if(max==0)
    {
        %><tr><td></td><td colspan="5" class="viewa"><% out.println("No Records found."); %></td><%
    }
    else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            %><tr><td><input class="tablechkbox" type="radio" name="prodAlertsRad"/></td><%

            List r=new ArrayList();
            r=(List)result.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<r.size();j++)
            {
                %><td class="viewa"><%out.print(r.get(j));%></td><%
            }
            %></tr><%
        } 
    }
    %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can test it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NK5j/4/)

Comment: How do you know if the data is a URL or not? Just by parsing it? Why would you need jQuery to do that?

Comment: @JBNizet: by identifying if it contains `http`.. jquery because I am using it, any other thing is also acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make change in this part of your code.

```
for(int j=0;j<r.size();j++) 
{
   %><td class="viewa"><%out.print(r.get(j));%></td><%             
}
```

to make your url work as hyperlink, you need to use anchor tag inside ur `td`. Also, it is important to know the exact index where your `url` lies in the list `r`. Since in your case, url is at the last index, we can modify the code this way-

```
for(int j=0;j<r.size()-1;j++) //changed to size-1
{
   %><td class="viewa"><%out.print(r.get(j));%></td><%             
}
 %><td class="viewa"><a href="<%out.print(r.get(r.size()-1));%>"><%out.print(r.get(r.size()-1));%></a></td><%
```

you might need to do little handling to avoid `indexOutOfBoundException`. I leave it for u to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
    {
        %><tr><td><input class="tablechkbox" type="radio" name="prodAlertsRad"/></td><%

        List r=new ArrayList();
        r=(List)result.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<r.size();j++)
        {
            if(j==r.size()-1){%>
        <td class="viewa"><a href="<%out.print(r.get(j));%>"><%out.print(r.get(j));%></a>
    <%}else{
            %><td class="viewa"><%out.print(r.get(j));%></td><%}
        }
        %></tr><%
    }
```